# sbclでscriptオプションを利用したさいにquicklispが利用できなくなってしまう

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

Common Lispの練習のため、sbcl(Steel Bank Common Lisp)で、簡単なスクリプトを書いてるのですが、`sbcl --script foobar.lisp`を実行した際に、`quicklisp`がロード出来ないというエラーが出てしまいます。このときに、`quicklisp`を利用するためには、いったいどうすればいいのでしょうか?

詳細のエラーメッセージは以下の通りです:

```
Unhandled SB-C::INPUT-ERROR-IN-LOAD in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD
                                                "main thread" RUNNING
                                                 {10039B67E3}>:
  READ error during LOAD:

    Package QL does not exist.

      Line: 1, Column: 12, File-Position: 12

      Stream: #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM
                for "file /home/esehara/commonlisp/foobar.lisp"
                {10039B97B3}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、原因ですが、--scriptオプションは、

```
--no-userinit --no-sysinit --disable-debugger
```

を指定しているのと同じとのことですので、ユーザーの初期化ファイルを読まず、初期化ファイルで指定しているであろうQuicklispの読み込みが行なわれない為です。

- http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Shebang-Scripts

これを避けるには他の方も回答しているように--loadオプションを使ってしまうことが考えられます。

他の選択肢としては、Quicklispを読み込んでしまったイメージをダンプして使うことも考えられます。
SBCLだと、実行可能ファイルが作成できますので、下記のようにしてQuicklisp込みのsbclを作成してしまえば可能です。

ダンプ方法

```
(cl:progn
  ;; .sbclrc に書かれている内容
  (cl:let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                            (user-homedir-pathname))))
    (cl:when (cl:probe-file quicklisp-init)
      (cl:load quicklisp-init)))

  ;; Quicklispが読み込み済みの実行可能ファイルをsbqlとして作成
  (sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die "sbql" :purify t :executable t))
```

スクリプト例

```
(defun fib (n)
  (if (< n 2)
      n
    (+ (fib (1- n))
       (fib (- n 2)))))

;; 最近のQuicklispにはsilentオプションが付いた。
(ql:quickload :cl-ppcre :silent t)

(print (fib 30))
(terpri)
```

-

```
$ ./sbql --script ./fib.lisp                        

832040
```

下記のように、shebangスクリプトにすることも可能です。

```
#!/usr/local/bin/sbql --script
```

イメージのダンプというと面倒臭そうな印象がありますが、実際はそれ程のことでもありませんし、こちらの方が手軽なこともあります。

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sbcl --noinform --quit --load foo.lisp
```

として実行して下さい。

**追記**

ただしこの場合、shebangには使えませんので、shebangから起動する場合は --script を使う必要があります。ご注意下さい。

Comment: むりやりshebangというか実行属性をつけたスクリプトで使うの、スクリプトの1行目をこれで始めるというのはどうですか:

`:>/dev/null; exec sbcl --noinform --quit --load $0 "$@"`

Answer (score 0):

前の方も書いていますが、homedir下の.sbclrcファイルが読み込まれていないのが原因です。
したがって、.sbclrcを読み込んでやれば、うまくいきます。

```
(load (merge-pathnames
         (make-pathname
          :name ".sbclrc")
         (user-homedir-pathname)))
```